# If $\int_{\Bbb R^2}|f(x+iy)|\,dx\,dy<\infty$ then prove that $f\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

> Let , $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be an entire function and $\displaystyle \int_{\Bbb R^2}|f(x+iy)|\,dx\,dy<\infty$. Then prove that $f(z)=0$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$.

Put $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$. Then , integration becomes $\displaystyle \int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|r\,d\theta\,dr<\infty$. But from here I'm unable to conclude nothing.! How I proceed? Any hint please.

Comment: Louisville's theorem?

Comment: How you apply Liouville's theorem ?

Comment: @SteveD What is "Louisville's Theorem?"  There is a [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)) to which you are likely referring.

Comment: It's not immediately clear that $f$ is necessarily bounded -- in real calculus, there are unbounded functions that belong to $L^p$ for all $p$ finite but not in $L^\infty$

Comment: Also, I believe you have the order of integration incorrect ($r$ does not range between $0$ and $2\pi$)

Comment: @Nitin I don't mean that the limit of $r$. I just cleared it.

Comment: @nitin: this function is smooth.

Comment: @drmv: yes, clearly I meant that. Phone autocorrected it.

Comment: @SteveD what does smoothness have to do with anything? OP was integrating $\theta$ between 0 and $\infty$ and $r$ between $0$ and $2\pi$. Doesn't matter, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:*  Use the estimate from Cauchy's integral formula
$$
\lvert f^{(n)}(0) \rvert \le \frac{n!}{2 \pi r^n} \int_0^{2\pi} 
\lvert f(re^{i\theta}) \rvert \, d\theta
$$
to show that
$$
 \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|r\,d\theta \, dr
$$
cannot be finite unless $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: I'm not getting..please extend something.

Comment: All too easy!  (+1)

Comment: @S717717: $\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|r\,d\theta \, dr \ge \int_0^R \frac{2\pi}{n!}\lvert f^{(n)}(0) \rvert r^{n+1} \, dr = ...$